# DoExpressCheckout 10004 - no additional error messages

Tags: paypal

We have an issue with our PayPal Express Checkout integration. We see an error coming back from **DoExpressCheckout** with code **10004** saying "**Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details**." But the response contains no additional error messages.

This occurs randomly with our integration. It started approximately one month ago and has happened 70 times vs 1430 successful transactions.

It appears to be random. Not tied to any specific amounts, browser type, time of transaction etc. One user could have several failures then try again with the same token and have it go through. Some users have come back 10 minutes later or change browser and it works. Most give up.

I'd appreciate any suggestions, is there a way to retrieve any more debug for this error?

**SetExpressCheckout**

```
USER=XXX
PWD=XXX
SIGNATURE=XXX
VERSION=112
METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
ALLOWNOTE=0
ADDROVERRIDE=1
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME=Mr X
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET=Test St
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET2=
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY=City
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE=State
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP=5000
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=AU
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM=8888888888
RETURNURL=URLA
CANCELURL=URLB
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Authorization
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=AUD
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=20.9
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=DOOM PATROL VOL 6 #3
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=7.95
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=SEP160206
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE0=AUD
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1=MOTHER PANIC #1
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1=7.95
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER1=SEP160201
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1=1
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE1=AUD
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME2=Regular Post (cannot be tracked)
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT2=5
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER2=Freight
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY2=1
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE2=AUD
```

**GetExpressCheckout**

```
USER=XXX
PWD=XXX
SIGNATURE=XXX
VERSION=2.3
TOKEN=EC-5DX46556HG972093T
METHOD=GetExpressCheckoutDetails
```

**DoExpressCheckout**

```
USER=XXX
PWD=XXX
SIGNATURE=XXX
VERSION=2.3
PAYMENTACTION=Authorization
PAYERID=XXX
TOKEN=EC-5DX46556HG972093T
AMT=20.9
CURRENCYCODE=AUD
METHOD=DoExpressCheckoutPayment
```

**PayPal returns:**

```
TOKEN=EC-5DX46556HG972093T
TIMESTAMP=2016-11-23T10:53:35Z
CORRELATIONID=XXX
ACK=Failure
VERSION=2.3
BUILD=000000
L_ERRORCODE0=10004
L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Internal Error
L_LONGMESSAGE0=Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.
L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error
```

Comment: Contacted paypal and they are aware of the issue and are investigating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was on PayPals side. If you have the same issue just log a support ticket and magic will happen.